# spring mvc outputStream csv

Tags: java, spring, csv, spring-boot, fileoutputstream

How to split de code into Service, repository and controller (Spring mvc)
this code work for me but not good split.
Big table large table to expose API REST

```
    @ApiOperation(value = "Search all customers",response = GoldenCustomer.class)
    @RequestMapping(value = "/goldenall/",method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json")
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity<?> getAllCustomers(HttpServletResponse response){
        LOGGER.info("Get all Golden Customers...");
        List<GoldenCustomer> goldenCustomers = null;
        String message = "Unknown exception";
        try {

            PreparedStatement st = session.prepare("select * from ckm_d_pilot.golden_clusters_by_customer where solr_query=?");
            //TODO
            String input_string = "*";
            String solrQuery = "{\"q\": \"*:"+input_string+"\", \"paging\": \"driver\"}";
            BoundStatement boundSt = st.bind(solrQuery);
            ResultSet rs = session.execute(boundSt.setFetchSize(1000));
            response.setContentType("text/csv");
            response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=export.csv;");
            ServletOutputStream os = response.getOutputStream();
            for(Row row: rs){
                String csvLine = row.getString("cluster_id")+","+row.getString("src_customer_id")+"\n";
                os.write(csvLine.getBytes("UTF-8"));
            }
            response.flushBuffer();

        }catch (Exception e){


            LOGGER.error("Intetrnal error WebService exception not found "+ message, e);
            throw new ReportInternalException(message);
        }

        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the minimum refactored code which gives you some information on how it can be done.

```
@ApiOperation(value = "Search all customers",response = GoldenCustomer.class)
@RequestMapping(value = "/goldenall/",method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json")
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<?> getAllCustomers(HttpServletResponse response){
    LOGGER.info("Get all Golden Customers...");
    List<GoldenCustomer> goldenCustomers = null;
    String message = "Unknown exception";
    try {

        String custCsv = new CustomerServiceImpl().getAllCustomers();
        response.setContentType("text/csv");
        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=export.csv;");
        ServletOutputStream os = response.getOutputStream();
        os.write(custCsv.getBytes("UTF-8"));            
        response.flushBuffer();

    }catch (Exception e){

        LOGGER.error("Intetrnal error WebService exception not found "+ message, e);
        throw new ReportInternalException(message);
    }

    return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.OK);
}

public class CustomerServiceImpl {
    public String getAllCustomers () {
        return new CustomersDAOImpl().getAllCustomers();
    }

}

public class CustomersDAOImpl() {
    public String getAllCustomers() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        PreparedStatement st = session.prepare("select * from ckm_d_pilot.golden_clusters_by_customer where solr_query=?");
        //TODO
        String input_string = "*";
        String solrQuery = "{\"q\": \"*:"+input_string+"\", \"paging\": \"driver\"}";
        BoundStatement boundSt = st.bind(solrQuery);
        ResultSet rs = session.execute(boundSt.setFetchSize(1000));           
        for(Row row: rs){
            String csvLine = row.getString("cluster_id")+","+row.getString("src_customer_id")+"\n";
            sb.append(csvLine);                
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }

}
```

**Note:-** I have not tested the below code

Comment: tks for ansewer, but this method crashes for large tables with out-of-memory exception. step by step setFetchSize(1000) without interupting the connection

Comment: tks for ansewer, but this method crashes for large tables with out-of-memory exception. i need send step by step (setFetchSize(1000)) without interupting the connection